# Unresponsive laptop key

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have an MSI laptop and the "C" key is completely unresponsive. I've tried removing the key and pressing down on the button and it does not even work that way.

Is there a way I can repair this without replacing the entire keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of repair is slim from my personal experience, but to repair it you would have to remove the keyboard completely from the laptop and then see if you can remove the membrane (the rubber part the key presses) from the board.
If you can get that far you can try cleaning the contacts with alcohol wipes or some other electrical cleaner and reassembling to see if it's working again, but... you've already taken the keyboard out of the computer and torn it down. It would be rather easy at this point to just install a new one.
I personally tried this method on a few year old Acer laptop of mine trying to save $25, in the end it didn't want to go back together right but did work again. Yet it annoyed me because now it creaked when typing so I just replaced it.
Here is a very detailed and picture filled guide on how a very determined guy repaired his keyboard, and you can find others searching around on Google. It's for a desktop keyboard but the same principle applies.
https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/10836-how-to-fix-a-broken-membrane-keyboard-logitech-g15-gen1/